# Holding any key and then pressing shift will stop the key from repeating

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Since a couple of days, I'm experiencing a strange issue with my keyboard. When I hold down any key, such as A, the letter is repeated until I let go OR until I also press down my shift key and will not continue repeating as a capital letter even if I let got of shift again. Pressing shift first, then letting go works fine until I press down shift again. This is problematic when I try to switch from walking to running in many games. I can reproduce it with a different keyboard on the same PC. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug.  My keyboard works the same way.

Comment: Really? Then how have I ever been able to switch from walking to sprinting in games? Did that change with a windows update or something?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I do play games with this keyboard, and I haven't had any issues.  If I hold down "a" it will repeat until I press shift.  As soon as I press shift the repeating stops.  Interestingly, the inverse isn't true.  If I start with Shift + A it repeats, and if I let go of Shift it continues to repeat.

Comment: I'm using a Corsair K70 gaming keyboard.  Any chance you have the same?

Comment: Almost, I have a K95 RGB, but as I mentioned my cheapo Perixx keyboard does the same.

Comment: When you are in game, when you try to start sprinting instead you stop walking?

Comment: In BF5 when I strafe and naturally want to switch to sprinting I instead stop walking (and die immediately). I'll test another game tomorrow to see if it's a specific issue with that game perhaps.

Comment: The behavior you described is normal for any keyboard. If you're experiencing trouble in the game, it may be a game specific setting. The K95 keyboard has a 122 full key rollover and 100% anti-ghosting. With that keyboard you should not experience any problems when wanting to strafe and then sprint.

Comment: Thanks, I reset all the control settings in the affected game and the issue is fixed. Not sure what the original cause was, since I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the behaviour I described is standard on all (Windows?) computers and misled me into believing it caused my original issue.
In BF5, I reset all keyboard and control settings to default and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue with my w key. holding it down for a long time and letting go and it will continue pressing w for a couple more seconds. tested it out in notepad. i fixed the issue by uninstalling the keyboard software in control panel>devices and printer>device manager>keyboards> the keyboards listed there. when you uninstall the device and restart computer it will download the pack again. that fixed my issue. hope that helps